# Can't SSH into Google Cloud Engine. Boot errors

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine

I cannot ssh into my instance. I tried the following

- Created new ssh key pairs and added the project, but that didn't help. I create a brand new instance in the same project and I could ssh easily. So, I don't think the ssh keys are the problem.
- "Block project-wide SSH keys" is not selected either
- Created a machine image and spawned a new instance, that had the same problem
- Enable serial console with the "startup-script" but that didn't help either. It simply won't accept the password.

```bash
    #! /bin/bash
    adduser serial1
    echo serial1:desperate-attempt | chpasswd
    usermod -aG google-sudoers serial1
```

- I don't think it's a disk space issue. Instance has 10 GB disk.  I only write to a log file and last I checked it was ~50 MB. I also don't see disk space errors in console logs

I did see these errors in the "Serial port 1 (console)" logs

```
Oct 16 16:29:01 instance-1 ntpd[668]: bind(21) AF_INET6 fe80::4001:aff:fe8e:2%2#123 flags 0x11 failed: Cannot assign requested address
Oct 16 16:29:01 instance-1 ntpd[668]: unable to create socket on eth0 (5) for fe80::4001:aff:fe8e:2%2#123
Oct 16 16:29:01 instance-1 ntpd[668]: failed to init interface for address fe80::4001:aff:fe8e:2%2
Oct 16 16:29:01 instance-1 ntpd[668]: Listening on routing socket on fd #21 for interface updates
Oct 16 16:29:02 instance-1 ntpd[668]: bind(24) AF_INET6 fe80::4001:aff:fe8e:2%2#123 flags 0x11 failed: Cannot assign requested address
Oct 16 16:29:02 instance-1 ntpd[668]: unable to create socket on eth0 (6) for fe80::4001:aff:fe8e:2%2#123
Oct 16 16:29:02 instance-1 ntpd[668]: failed to init interface for address fe80::4001:aff:fe8e:2%2
Oct 16 16:29:02 instance-1 google_instance_setup[663]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Oct 16 16:29:02 instance-1 google_instance_setup[663]:   File "/usr/bin/google_instance_setup", line 6, in <module>
Oct 16 16:29:02 instance-1 google_instance_setup[663]:     from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
Oct 16 16:29:02 instance-1 google_instance_setup[663]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3257, in <module>
Oct 16 16:29:02 instance-1 google_instance_setup[663]:     def _initialize_master_working_set():
Oct 16 16:29:02 instance-1 google_instance_setup[663]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3240, in _call_aside
Oct 16 16:29:02 instance-1 google_instance_setup[663]:     f(*args, **kwargs)
Oct 16 16:29:02 instance-1 google_instance_setup[663]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3269, in _initialize_master_working_set
Oct 16 16:29:02 instance-1 google_instance_setup[663]:     working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
Oct 16 16:29:02 instance-1 google_instance_setup[663]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 582, in _build_master
Oct 16 16:29:02 instance-1 google_instance_setup[663]:     ws.require(__requires__)
Oct 16 16:29:02 instance-1 google_instance_setup[663]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 899, in require
Oct 16 16:29:02 instance-1 google_instance_setup[663]:     needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
Oct 16 16:29:02 instance-1 google_instance_setup[663]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 785, in resolve
Oct 16 16:29:02 instance-1 google_instance_setup[663]:     raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
Oct 16 16:29:02 instance-1 google_instance_setup[663]: pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'google-compute-engine==2.8.13' distribution was not found and is required by the application
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Google Compute Engine Instance Setup.
```

```
Oct 16 16:29:02 instance-1 google_instance_setup[663]: pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'google-compute-engine==2.8.13' distribution was not found and is required by the application
[[0;1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Google Compute Engine Instance Setup.
See 'systemctl status google-instance-setup.service' for details.
         Starting NSS cache refresh...
Oct 16 16:29:02 instance-1 systemd[1]: google-instance-setup.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 16 16:29:02 instance-1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Google Compute Engine Instance Setup.
Oct 16 16:29:02 instance-1 systemd[1]: google-instance-setup.service: Unit entered failed state.
Oct 16 16:29:02 instance-1 systemd[1]: google-instance-setup.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The above errors are repeated for google_accounts_daemon, google_metadata_script_runner, google_network_daemon, google_*,..

It sounds like some package is not up-to-date. But how do I install without logging into the instance? Is there a good way to fix this error?

Comment: 1) Is this a new instance or an instance that has been running successfully for a while? 2) You will probably find a message that the system is out of disk space. If that is the case, resize the boot disk. 3) Review the logs for errors running your startup script. If your instance is out of disk space, you cannot run a startup script - no place to store the script.

Comment: 1) The instance has been up for 1+ years now. 
2) I don't see error messages for "disk", "space", "out of"

`virtio-scsi vendor='Google' product='PersistentDisk' rev='1' type=0 removable=0`
`virtio-scsi blksize=512 sectors=20971520 = 10240 MiB`

3) added more logs to the main post. 

Thank you @JohnHanley

Comment: The error message that you posted are side effects of the real problem. Go back to the start of the boot log and find the issue that is causing the problem.

Comment: I didn't find anything on quick searches. Will go through line by line. Brb

Comment: I bumped up the disk to 20GB to eliminate as a possibility. I still can't decipher the errors. The full log is here https://pastebin.com/3Nr3EWHt

I appreciate your help!

Comment: I went through the log file. The system is booting to the login prompt and the SSH server appears to be running. The Google packages or the Python installation is broken. Create a new instance, mount the problem system's disk on the new instance and copy off your data. My website has an article on how to recover from UFW lockout that shows the steps to move the disk drive to a new instance.  I do not think your instance is recoverable except by an expert. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-recovering-from-ufw-lockout/

Comment: That helped! Feel free to post that as answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your instance, either the Google Cloud packages or the Python installation or both are broken. This issue prevents you from being able to log in.

I recommend that you create a new instance and move the persistent disks from the broken instance to the new instance.

**STEP 1:**

Create a new instance in the same zone. A micro instance will work.

**STEP 2:**

Open a Cloud Shell prompt (this also works from your desktop if gcloud is set up). Execute this command. Replace NAME with your instance name (broken system) and DISK with the boot disk name and ZONE with the zone that the system is in:

```
gcloud compute instances detach-disk NAME --disk=DISK --zone=ZONE
```

Make sure that the previous command did not report an error.

**STEP 3:**

Attach this disk to the new instance that you created.

Make sure that the new VM instance is running before attaching the second disk. Sometimes an instance can get confused on which disk to boot from if more than one disk is bootable.

Go to Compute Engine -> VM instances. Click on your instance. Click Edit. Under "Additional disks" click "Add item". For name enter/select the disk that you detached from your broken instance. Click Save.

**STEP 4:**

SSH into your new instance with both disks attached.

**STEP 5:**

Follow these steps carefully. Mount the second disk onto the root file system as a subdirectory.

- Become superuser. Execute sudo -s
- Execute the command **df -h**. Make sure that /dev/sdb1 is not mounted.
- Create a directory for the mount point: **mkdir /mnt/oldsystem**
- Mount the second disk: **mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/oldsystem**

You can now access the files from the old file system at the path **/mnt/oldsystem**.