# Not able to login to Debian 8 GCP VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, debian-based

Can anyone please help me with this? I'm not able to access a Debian 8 GCP VM via SSH and also the serial console. That VM had an additional disk and after restart I'm not able to SSH. I even tried to connect to it via serial port and it showed me the below message.

```
You are in emerg
Cannot open access to console, the root account is locked.
See sulogin(8) man page for more details
```

Comment: This is a common Fedora problem .. You'll need to boot from a live disk and unlock the root account and set a password ..

Comment: How can boot from a live disk? It's a Google cloud VM and it is debian 8.

Comment: This may help you in that case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69597655/cant-ssh-into-google-cloud-engine-boot-errors

Answer (score 3):

You cannot recover the virtual machine - just the data.

Create a new instance. Detach the disk(s) and attach to the new instance. Copy your data to the new instance. Optionally delete the old instance and disks.